# Save Bitmap to disk and release saved file Rendered from DevDept Eyeshot

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, eyeshot

In a WPF application, I need to save a Bitmap to disk and than after some changes I try to delete the saved file and save again the modified image.

The problem is once saved, the bitmap doesn't release the file and throws an exception when I try to delete it.

```
       //Gets a bitmap from DevDept.EyeShot model via Scene.RenderToBitmap() and save it to disk
       using (var bmpRight = Scene.RenderToBitmap(new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)))
       {
         bmpRight.Save(rightPath.Replace(".stl", ".jpg"));
       }
```

Than the user modifies the 3D model and tries to save again with the same name. (Because it is associated to an appointment).

When I try to delete it

```
      if (System.IO.File.Exists(rightPath.Replace(".stl", ".jpg")))
         System.IO.File.Delete(rightPath.Replace(".stl", ".jpg"));
```

I throws an error :

The process cannot access the file because it is in use by another process.

If I do the same thing without Scene2.RenderToBitmap() method of the 3D plateforme, it doesn't produce any error. But, how can it be ? There is no relation between the physical file and the plateforme!

Any idea pleae ?

Comment: Don't `Dispose` an object twice: by `using {...}` and `bmpRight.Dispose();`

Comment: Since it's a WPF application, is there a BitmapImage that shows the image from that file?

Comment: I tried it before and added Dispose() after but the same result.

Comment: Clemens, no, I save it but don't show anywhere.

Comment: But if it doesn't fix it, remove the double dispose, i guess

Comment: Jeroen Van Langen, Yes, after trying, I removed it.

Comment: Keithernet, the exception is The process cannot access the file MYFILEPATH  because it is in use by another process.

Comment: If you are positively sure there is no other bitmap object in your application that keeps the file open, there must apparently be some other application. An image viewer, or virus scanner?

Comment: Clemence, I am pretty sure that the Scene2.RenderToBitmap method of the 3D component causes this because if I create an empty bitmap and do the same thing, it works. But I can't understand. There is no link between the component and the file.